# Python - classmethod( )

Tags: python, generator, standard-library, class-method

Reading Python Standard Library.  Trying to understanding classmethod.

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(x,y):
        print('words')
```

When I type:

```
print(classmethod(C))
```

It returns:

```
<classmethod object at 0x00FAD930>
```

How would see what the classmethod returns instead of a generator of the classmethod?

Comment: You don't have a generator of the classmethod. You have the classmethod descriptor object.

Comment: Did you try : `C.f(1,2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are producing a `classmethod` descriptor object:

```
print(classmethod(C))
```

returns the class `C` wrapped in a new `classmethod` object. This is not a generator, this is what Python actually stores in your class when you decorate a method with it.

Remember that a `@decorator_expression` line above a function or class is just syntactic sugar for an extra function call replacing that object; `@classmethod` above `def f(...)` just means that Python will replace `f` with `f = classmethod(f)`.

You can see the same type of object when looking at the `C.__dict__['f']` value; that's same type of object:

```
>>> class C:
...     @classmethod
...     def f(x,y):
...         print('words')
... 
>>> C.__dict__['f']
<classmethod object at 0x107d00810>
>>> C.__dict__['f'].__get__(None, C)
<bound method type.f of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> C.f
<bound method type.f of <class '__main__.C'>>
```

It is the `__get__` method on the descriptor object that is invoked when you try and access the `C.f` attribute.

Functions themselves are descriptors too; a `classmethod` bypasses the function's `.__get__` method to provide a binding to the class instead of the normal binding to an instance.

See the [descriptor HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to understand what a descriptor is, and how a `classmethod` object works.

To see what an the method itself returns, just call it on the class or on an instance:

```
>>> class C:
...     @classmethod
...     def f(*args, **kw):
...         return args, kw
...     def regular(*args, **kw):
...         return args, kw
... 
>>> C.f()
((<class '__main__.C'>,), {})
>>> C().f()
((<class '__main__.C'>,), {})
>>> C.regular()
((), {})
>>> C().regular()
((<__main__.C object at 0x1085b0790>,), {})
```

Instead of the usual `self` instance object, the method is instead passed a reference to the class. For both the `C.f()` call (directly on the class) and the `C().f()` (on an instance of `C`), the first argument to `f()` is `C` itself.

Compare this to the `C.regular()` method; this is a normal method and when called directly on the class with `C.regular()` no arguments were passed in, when called on an instance with `C().regular()` a first argument, the instance, was passed in. This is what you normally would  use `self` for in the method signature.

For class methods, then the first argument is usually named `cls` when declaring your method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call the `classmethod` `f` you have created on `C`, you should do:

```
C.f(...)
```

[`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) is the decorator function, it will wrap whatever you pass to it and return a `classmethod object`:

```
>>> classmethod(1)
<classmethod object at 0x02FA6370>
```

Note that the first to a `classmethod` is the class itself, called `cls` by convention:

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, x, y):
        print("words")
```

This gives:

```
>>> C.f(1, 2)
words
```

Alternatively `return` the value and `print` it outside the function:

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, x, y):
        return "words"

>>> print(C.f(1, 2))
words
```

Answer (score 1):

classmethod is useful when sharing the value across all different objects being created.

```
class Classtest:
    a =10
    @classmethod
    def hi(cls, x):
        cls.a= cls.a+x
        print cls.a

h = Classtest()
h.hi(10)

b = Classtest()
b.hi(30)

c = Classtest()
c.hi(40)

>>> ================================ RESTART     ================================
>>>  
20
50
90
```

Here the value of variable a is shared across all different objects that are being created and not just limited to one instance

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, x, y):
        return 'words'
```

Unlike traditional class methods where the first argument is a `self` reference, a class method receives the `class` as implicit first argument, just like an instance method receives the instance.

Also, you need to return a value to print it.